# Declaring a using declaration before using it in other using declarations

Tags: c++, declaration, using

Is it possible to declare a using declaration before using it?

I would like to do something like:

```
using V = std::vector< V >;
```

or like:

```
using X, Y; // declaring X and Y
using Node = std::variant< X, Y >;
using X = std::unordered_vector< Node >;
using Y = std::vector< Node >;
```

Is it possible?

---

EDIT: The comments are focusing on the `V` I defined more than I meant.

I don't need that type, but it's the most minimal example I could think of to show the problem. The second example, with `X`, `Y` and `Node` is closer to what I need. Another similar example could be: `using MyList = std::pair<Data, MyList*>`.

These types I'm bringing up as examples are types that make sense and should be able to exist. I could define `V`, `Node`,  `MyList` etc by defining my own structs, like: `struct V{ V* start; V* end; /*all the other methods here*/ };`... But since there are already plenty types defined in `std` and with a ton of well defined semantics (constructors, operators, iterator stuff, trait types specialized for them etc), I would not want to redefine identical types.

Is it possible to create "recursive" (especially indirectly recursive, like the `Node` or `MyList` examples) types using using-declarations?

Comment: I feel like this might be an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `std::vector< V >` where `V` is itself `std::vector< V >` makes no sense - it's turtles all the way down. How many pairs of square brackets do you plan to use to access an element of this beast, and what would be the type of that element?

Comment: So you want `V` to consist of a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which holds a sequence of elements, each of which ...?

Comment: You can already do this in C++. It's called generic types. In C++ 20, we also get access to constraints and concepts which further solidify the types and their usage

Comment: `V = std::vector<V>` can be used to create a tree of possibly infinite size, without data. Might be useful if one is interested only in the "shape" of the tree.

Comment: Anyways, the two examples I posted are the most minimal examples I could think of, without any superfluous business logic. What I'm trying to achieve with those examples is possible and well defined: I can create something equivalent to `V = std::vector<V>` if I define my own vector class (something like `struct V{V*start, V*end;};` etc). Can I do that with `std::vector`? Or more generically: is possible to declare a using-declaration before using it? Often I would need to do it, but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @Helloer I suppose that creating leaves by making a vector empty is one way to break out of the cycle. It seems rather inefficient though. Why not use traditional methods to create the tree, and just not store data in it? (Still seems inefficient, but at least it uses known methods.)

Comment: If instead you make `V` a `struct` you can forward declare it and make a `std::vector` of smart pointers to `V`. Then you can define `V` to have one such vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The pointer indirection isn't even required. `struct X { std::vector<X> vec; };` works just fine.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I know, but I have to define a struct virtually identical to `std::vector`, implement constructors, operators, begin and end, specialize templates etc etc... when `std::vector` arleady exists...

Comment: I mean, you could also do `struct X : std::vector<X> {};` but there be dragons if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Why everybody is focusing so much on that "recursive" vector? I thought that picking the most minimal example I could think of would make my question more clear. I didn't mean to start a philosophical discussion about the meaning of that type.

Comment: @Helloer Well, the answer to your question is straightforward: no, that's not possible. So people are focusing on the more interesting part of your question. :)

Comment: @cdhowie: ok, I was not sure that it wasn't possible, thanks. I wonder why. your idea of doing `struct V : std::vector<V> {};` is brilliant, thanks. Would you know how to achieve indirect recursion between using-declarations too, using the same method or different ones?

Comment: @Helloer You'd need to do basically the same thing. This can't work with aliases because you'd have infinite template recursion: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector< .....` and so on. That type cannot exist. You have to break the recursion with a type that composes/inherits the recursive type.

Comment: @cdhowie: thinking about it, your solution works for indirect recursion too. I just need to define one struct inheriting a type for each type, declare those structs and use them inside the other types (`struct Y; struct Node: std::variant<X, Y>{}; struct Y: std::vector<Node>{};` etc). I'm happy to accept your suggestion, if you write it as an aswer!

Comment: @Helloer I am working on an answer but note that the specific approach you give there won't work because instantiating `std::variant` requires its type arguments to be complete.

Comment: @cdhowie: true, I only tried after the previous comment. I can define my subclass of `std::variant` after every non-pointer, non-reference type it contains (i.e. in the example above, after the definition of the `std::vector`). Possibly this solution might not work with some cases, but it should work for most (including my real problem).

Comment: @Helloer I would propose that everybody was focusing so much on that "recursive" vector because that is what your question focused on before your edit. (The code defining `V`, `X`, and `Y` comprised 57% of the non-space characters in the original question.) You could take this as an object lesson as to why one should use *text* to ask a question and use code only as an illustration.

Comment: @JaMiT: right, next time I'll try to phrase the problem more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with `using` doesn't work because this simply introduces a new name for an existing type.  `using V = std::vector<V>;`, if it were even allowed, would lead to infinite recursion in the compiler when it tries to determine what type `V` even is.

One approach that could work would be to inherit `std::vector<V>` from a type `V`. (`using vector::vector;` brings the `vector` constructors into `V`.)

```
struct V : std::vector<V> { using vector::vector; };
```

This breaks the recursion. `std::vector<V>` works because `V` is its own type. The fact that `V` inherits `std::vector<V>` is irrelevant to this point.

Note that you can't `delete` a type through a pointer to a base type when the base doesn't declare a virtual destructor. This causes undefined behavior:

```
std::vector<V> * ptr = new V(); // Permitted, implicit pointer upcast
delete ptr;                     // Undefined behavior
```

It will also be very easy to accidentally slice the base object, though the consequences of doing so may be immaterial in this case.

This same approach can work for your other example:

```
class Node;

using X = std::set<Node>;
using Y = std::vector<Node>;

struct Node : std::variant<X, Y> { using variant::variant; };
```

Comment: Thanks, both for the idea and for pointing out the "risky" undefined behavior of deleting the superclass. I suspect that in practice it should work with every compiler, and in my case I don't think I would destroy the upcasted type anyways.

Comment: @Helloer It very well may not work in every compiler. If the subobject is not located at the exact same memory location as the most-derived object, `delete` won't be able to find the allocation metadata to properly deallocate.

Comment: Sure, but I would be surprised if any compiler put my type and the superclass at different addresses: single inheritance, nothing virtual, no data members...

Comment: @Helloer Most likely, yes. Just keep in mind that "works fine on this compiler" is another way of saying "could stop working on a future compiler version."

Answer (score 1):

`using` does not create new types.  It only introduces aliases for existing types.  You can't introduce an alias for a type that doesn't exist, which is what both of your examples try to do.

For example, what is the full name of the type for which `V` is an alias?  It's `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<...>>>>`.  That's not a type that exists, so you can't create an alias for it.